# Unexpected output in simple C code

Tags: c

I am working on the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

# define CONSTANT 5+7
int main()
{
    int y = 5;
    int z = 10;

    y = CONSTANT / y;
    printf("y= %d\n", y);
    z /= CONSTANT;
    printf("z= %d\n", z);

}
```

I understand `z = 10 / 12` = `0` which is the output I get for `z`. But `y = 12 / 5`=`2` should be the answer but I get `y = 6`. Why is it so?

Comment: `CONSTANT` is not `12`. You defined it as `5+7`.

Comment: Macro expansion is first so `y = 5 + 7 / y` which is `y = 5 + (7 / y)`. You should probably use `const` or at least put `5 + 7` in brackets.

Comment: Are you sure you know what the result of CONSTANT 5+7 is?

Comment: To hammer the point home, you might have to read a bit about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: I have written [a document](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/2006/common-pitfalls/11668/macros-are-simple-string-replacements#t=201608010319270890472) about this.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations on discovering one of the most dangerous sides of macros: they are textual substitutions, not true expressions. Therefore, the compiler sees your code as

```
y= 5 + 7 / y;
```

applies the standard rules of precedence, and gets a six.

When you cannot avoid a preprocessor definition for an expression, use parentheses:

```
#define CONSTANT (5+7)
```

Answer (score 3):

`y = CONSTANT / y;` expands to `y = 5+7 / y;`.

And, `/` operator has higher precedence than `+` operator, so `7 / y` is evaluated first, which is equal to `1`.  So, `y` will be equal to `5 + 1` which is equal to `6`.

Answer (score 1):

Executing `clang -E main.c`(which means preprocessing only):

```
int main()
{
    int y = 5;
    int z = 10;

    y = 5+7 / y;
    printf("y= %d\n", y);
    z /= 5+7;
    printf("z= %d\n", z);

}
```

The problem should be obvious now. When defining a macro, we usually use parentheses to avoid such error: `#define CONSTANT (5+7)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the macro in parenthesis like `#define CONSTANT (5+7)` otherwise division is performed first and it will be like y = 5 + (7/5), which is 5+(1) = 6.